# How to remove HTML properties in Search Result

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I have created a custom search page and my search results show HTML properties of my search results.  How do I remove those from showing and just keep the title and url of the searched page.  Highlighted in Yellow is the content I want to hide or remove from the search results. SharePoint Online Classic Wiki Template

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In [SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-resultsoption-1), this section displays contents from a managed property called `Content Summary`. This managed property is not available in SharePoint Online.

However, you can hide the item summaries from the current page by using CSS in a Script Editor web part. Here is a sample script:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-srch-item-summary {display:none !important;}
</style>
```

`ms-srch-item-summary` is the class name for this section in my test environment.

Comment: That worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Jeremyjdz Would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well. Thanks.